# Excel Return Share Closing Price for Previous Date

Tags: excel-formula

Using the shares tool under the data tab, I'm hoping to be able to retrieve a closing share price from a date in the past.

I have a spreadsheet to track shares that I own. I have fields for date of sale and number of shares sold, as well as sale price which is manually updated. I want the application to call the date field and return the closing price on this date so I can calculate proceeds automatically.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Can you show some sample data, without it you may get some answer but that may not work on your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is one row that matches your criteria (i.e. you do not enter the data twice, and the data is present), you can use `SUMIFS`:
`=SUMIFS(closing, shares, shareref, dates, dateref)`

I used named ranges, which you have to subsitute with your cell or range references:

- closing = column (range) with the closing share prices
- shares = column with the name or reference of the share
- dates = column with the dates
- shareref = cell with the name or reference of the share you want the closing share price for
- dateref = cell with the date you want the closing share price for

Please note that `SUMIFS` is intended to sum values that meet several criteria, but if you know that only one data point meets the criteria, then the sum is the same as the value itself of course. I would actually recommend to use could use `AVERAGEIFS` instead, as if there are two duplicate values, it still works.